# Capistrano deployment on Windows machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, deployment, capistrano

I have been trying to deploy a rails application using capistrano. However I am not able to reach the end of deployment and there is no way to figure out why. The script returns an error code 256 and stops at the following line in the deploy script

```
Command bundle exec rake assets:clean && EXECJS_RUNTIME='Node' JRUBY_OPTS='-J-d32 -X-C' bundle exec rake            assets:precompile returned status code 256
```

There is no more explanation to it. Has anybody faced the similar issue while deploying on windows?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information on the context of your situation. For instance, show the relevant code from your deploy.db file. That could tell us more about a possible problem source.

As a tip, when facing capistano deploying bugs, use the debugging flag to get more verbose output, and step through the process.

```
    cap deploy:cold -d
```

Anywho... I was facing a similar problem, while optimizing my capistrano deploying times. In case you only want to modify your assets:precompile task, to include your EXECJS_RUNTIME and JRUBY_OPTS custom values, you could try doing this.

```
    set :jruby_opts, "-X-C"
    set :asset_env, "RAILS_GROUPS=assets EXECJS_RUNTIME='Node'"
```